# Alert return url path while alert variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#search-jobs").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            key = $('#myInput').val();
            location = $('#location').val();
            alert(key);
            alert(location);
        });
    });
</script>
<form autocomplete="off" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <input type="text" id="myInput" name="company" placeholder="Job title, keywords or company name">
    <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location">
    <button name="search-jobs" id="search-jobs" type="submit"><i class="la la-search"></i></button>
</div>
```

In this question I have create an autocomplete which is working fine. Now, what am I doing here? When I click on `search-jobs` it alert `myInput` value then alert `url` path like `http://localhost/jobportal/index.php` then redirect me on other page and url of other page is like `localhost/jobportal/noida` where `noida` is location. I don't know what is the problem is this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: You can return false after your last alert if you dont want the form to be submited.

Comment: it redirects you to your form action ,try changing it from javascript:void(0) to some url ,or use onsubmit event inplace of onclick

Comment: You can use `e.preventDefault();` function.

Comment: I got solution Actually `location` is already define in jQuery that's why it return me the url path in my alert but thank you to all of you for your valuable comments and reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you did not declare your variables properly.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search-jobs").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let key = $('#myInput').val();
        let location = $('#location').val();
        alert(key);
        alert(location);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form autocomplete="off" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" name="company" placeholder="Job title, keywords or company name">
        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location">
        <button name="search-jobs" id="search-jobs" type="submit"><i class="la la-search"></i>test</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

since your variable **location** is not defined inside the function, it is hoisted on top in window scope. So your location variable is actually **window.location**, to which you are providing a value. Simple solution is try changing the name of variable or defining it inside the function with **let var** or **const**.

Comment: Brother that's what let does. It limits the the scope inside the function only and it will not be hoisted on top.

Answer (score 1):

```
let key = $('#myInput').val();
let location = $('#location').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code, here I have also updated the url with the url you have given in the description like "`localhost/jobportal/noida`"

```
   <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#search-jobs").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                key = $('#myInput').val();
                alert(key);
                loc =  location.host;           
                newloc = loc+"/jobportal/"+$('#location').val();
                alert(newloc);
                return false
            });
        });
    </script>
    <form autocomplete="off" action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" name="company" placeholder="Job title, keywords or company name">    
         <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location">    
        <button name="search-jobs" id="search-jobs"><i class="la la-search"></i></button>
    </div>
```